# Laravel 5 > touch pivot table (Many-to-Many)

Tags: laravel-5, pivot-table

Why is the **updated_at** field in my **pivot table** not updating giving the following setup?

Model

```
class Conversation extends Model {

    public function users()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
$conversation = Conversation::find($id);
$conversation->users()->touch();
```

The last line should - as far as I understand the whole thing - also update the pivots table updated_at field, shouldn´t it?

But it isn´t. Right now I have to do it manualy via a DB query.

Comment: Does this do anything? Do you get an error?

Comment: It´s touching the users updated_at fields while ignoring the pivot table. No errors.

Comment: If you added `->withPivot()` to your `users()` function, then tried `$conversation->users()->pivot->touch();` does it do anything? Or does it completely error out?

Comment: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::$pivot

Comment: Ok. I'm trying to test this without a database, so this is all theoretical lol... Try `$users = $conversation->users()->get();`, then loop over those users and access their `pivot` attribute: `foreach($users AS $user){ $user->pivot->touch(); }` You may be able to do this, or you may have to set each `pivot->updated_at = date("Y-m-d");` or whatever format you want. Let me know if any of those work.

Comment: This is actually working but doesn´t it mean for each user I´m doing a database query here?

Comment: Compared to DB::table('conversation_user')->where('conversation_id', $conversation_id)->update(['updated_at' => $time]) which is a single query

Comment: Yeah, that would be correct. `touch()` is a function that updates the column for `updated_at`, so it would be a single query for each call (as far as I can see anyway).

Comment: Ok, that´s sad but you helped me understand accessing the pivot model better. Because of the query amount I stick with the DB Class for now until I find a more of an "elegant laravel out of the box solution" :-) Thank you Tim Lewis.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is:

```
$conversation->users()->updateExistingPivot(
    $conversation->users()->get(),
    ['updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')]
);
```

It works for me (Laravel 5.7).